# Linq Right Outer Join Query in the C# MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to show the vehicles inside and outside the company by query. The query below shows the vehicles outside and vehicles with no track record. Vehicles inside and with tracking records are not visible.

How can this be done with a single query?

**TABLES**

[image]

**RECORDS**

[image]

**QUERY**

```
var VehiclesStatus = (from veh in db.Sec_Vehicle
                      join tracing in db.Sec_Tracing on veh.Id equals tracing.CarId into trc
                      from trace in trc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where trace.EntryDate == null || trace == null
                      orderby veh.Brand
                      select new VehicleStatus
                      {
                            Brand = veh.Brand,
                            Driver = trace != null ? trace.DriverName : string.Empty,
                            ReleaseDate = trace != null ? trace.ReleaseDate.ToString("HH:mm") : "",
                            Status = trace != null ? "Vehicle Busy" : "Vehicle Available"
                      }).ToList();
```

**THE RESULT I WANT**
[image]

thanks, kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks good. Just the problem in where clause (`where trace.EntryDate == null || trace == null`).

Example:

1.If you need WHERE condition try-

```
var VehiclesStatus = (from veh in db.Sec_Vehicle
                      join tracing in db.Sec_Tracing on veh.Id equals tracing.CarId into trc
                      from trace in trc.Where(f => f.EntryDate== null).DefaultIfEmpty()//use :f.EntryDate== null if you need which has no EntryDate OR f.EntryDate!= null if you need which has EntryDate
                      orderby veh.Brand
                      select new VehicleStatus
                      {
                            Brand = veh.Brand,
                            Driver = trace != null ? trace.DriverName : string.Empty,
                            ReleaseDate = trace != null ? trace.ReleaseDate.ToString("HH:mm") : "",
                            Status = trace != null ? "Vehicle Busy" : "Vehicle Available"
                      }).ToList();
```

2.Without Condition

```
var VehiclesStatus = (from veh in db.Sec_Vehicle
                      join tracing in db.Sec_Tracing on veh.Id equals tracing.CarId into trc
                      from trace in trc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      orderby veh.Brand
                      select new VehicleStatus
                      {
                            Brand = veh.Brand,
                            Driver = trace != null ? trace.DriverName : string.Empty,
                            ReleaseDate = trace != null ? trace.ReleaseDate.ToString("HH:mm") : "",
                            Status = trace != null ? "Vehicle Busy" : "Vehicle Available"
                      }).ToList();
```